Is there a way in JMESPath to remove null keys from data when query is run?
I am working with JSON data and using JMESPath to query and transform this data. I have a scenario where I need to remove keys with null values from my JSON objects dynamically. Here is an example of my input data:
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": null,
  "email": "john.doe@example.com",
  "phone": null
}

I want to transform this data to exclude any key-value pairs where the value is null, resulting in:
{
  "name": "John",
  "email": "john.doe@example.com"
}

The problem is that I am bound to use only JMESPath query to remove null keys. Is there a way to achieve this?

Are you using JMESPATH in python or all alone ? Because I saw that python version of JMESPATH have more feature and maybe you could do it with this version. I didn't succeed to find a solution to your problem but I got this : [{ind:@.name,all:{name:@.name}},{ind:@.age,all:{age:@.age}},{ind:@.email,all:{email:@.email}},{ind:@.phone,all:{phone:@.phone}}] | [?ind] | [*].values(@)[] | [?name||age||email||phone] . Maybe it could help. I think the merge function could help, but I don't have JMESPath on python, I will maybe install it later to try your challenge
